# why we generally dont use private variables in kotlin? like in java c++ etc

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I know that Kotlin generates getters and setters internally if we don't provide it but then the variable behaves just like a public variable in java which is considered bad in java programming, but not in Kotlin why?

Comment: Because they're not the same thing. In Java, declaring `public String field` gives you direct access to the field. In Kotlin, declaring `var field: String` does not because it's not actually the field, but a _property_. You can customize the the getter/setter of a property but that doesn't change how one _uses_ the property. For instance, using `obj.field = "new value"` literally uses the setter. The data is still completely encapsulated. In other words, a public property in Kotlin is equivalent to having the private field and public getter/setter in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to C#, Kotlin uses the concept of properties which means you can do something like

```
var name: String = “John”
```

Giving you a private field and public getters/setters.

Java does not have this and the fields are exposed if not defined as private or protected.

Comment: Not necessarily exposed. `default` fields are only exposed within the package, which has a similar behaviour to `protected` if there's no inheritance involved. This means unless `public` is defined, fields are *never* public.